# Font problems - TeX Live 2020 - Roboto Condensed does not work

Tags: fonts, texlive, debian, texlive-2020

New computer, new system (before Debian 10 with TeX Live 2019 (?); now Debian 11 with TeX Live 2020). My old documents no longer render correctly. I should have Roboto Condensed for title and subsections, and Venturis for paragraph text. Compare good output (PDFs from old computer):

[image]

With bad output (PDFs from new computer - zoom level slightly higher, ignore that):

[image]

I installed `texlive-fonts-extra` and all I could think of. Perhaps I'm missing something? This is my test file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf]{venturis}
\usepackage[condensed]{roboto}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\maketitle{%
    \begingroup
    \noindent
    \fontsize{24}{30}% 72pt on 80pt leading
    \robotocondensed
    Curriculum Vitae
    \par
    \vskip0.5em
    \noindent
    \Large
    First Last
    \par
    \noindent
    \Large
    ~
    \vskip1em
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Description

\subsubsection*{Main Interests and Statement}

Their artistic work ranges from \ldots{} to \ldots{}.

\end{document}
```

This is the full log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.1.10)  13 JAN 2022 17:28
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**now.tex
(./now.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count177
\c@section=\count178
\c@subsection=\count179
\c@subsubsection=\count180
\c@paragraph=\count181
\c@subparagraph=\count182
\c@figure=\count183
\c@table=\count184
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/venturisadf/venturis.sty
Package: venturis 2010/07/03 v1.005 VenturisADF PS

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count185
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nfssext-cfr/nfssext-cfr.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svn-prov/svn-prov.sty
Package: svn-prov 2010/04/24 v3.1862 Package Date/Version from SVN Keywords
)
Package: nfssext-cfr 2017/03/28 (SVN Rev: 6140){} specially mangled by cfr; bas
ed on 2003/03/14 v1.2 Experimental NFSS Extensions

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\c@taken=\count186
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 515.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 523.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 537.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \swshape on input line 544.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsw on input line 553.
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/roboto/roboto.sty
Package: roboto 2019/12/11 (Bob Tennent) Supports Roboto fonts for all LaTeX en
gines.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+yvt on input line 11
2.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/venturis/t1yvt.fd
File: t1yvt.fd 2010/07/03 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/yvt.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 54.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 58.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 62.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 66.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 94.

)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty
Package: fontaxes 2020/07/21 v1.0e Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \swshape on input line 35.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sscshape on input line 39.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ulcshape on input line 41.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsw on input line 47.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textssc on input line 48.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textulc on input line 49.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \robotoTOsF on input line 396.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-01-29 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count187
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
)
(./now.aux)
\openout1 = `now.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
\c@mv@tabular=\count188
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count189
 [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./now.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1748 strings out of 481158
 25893 string characters out of 5912464
 291703 words of memory out of 5000000
 18723 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 424193 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 36 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 68i,4n,74p,368b,125s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/share/t
exlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/venturisadf/t1-f_f-venturisadf.enc}</usr/shar
e/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/arkandis/venturis/yvtb8ac.pfb></usr/share/texl
ive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/arkandis/venturis/yvtr8ac.pfb>
Output written on now.pdf (1 page, 35622 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 17 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 11 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

One thing that might be different from the old computer, is I installed Roboto for office use (LibreOffice etc.) via a Debian package instead of manually. But I guess that doesn't interfere at all with the TeX installation?

I am using pdflatex. If I add option `sfdefault` to package `roboto`, the title is correct, but now everything is in Roboto, including the paragraph text (which should remain in the serif). Another strange thing is that the serif is coming out significantly more condensed than in the old version (compare screenshots), perhaps it is related to the warnings in the log?

Comment: it is a rather harmless warning and your document won't break. But you should notify the author of venturis so that they adapt their document, it doesn't follow the latex standards.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, thank you. But still the Roboto doesn't render. If I add option `sfdefault`, Roboto Condensed headings are correctly rendered, but  also the text body, which shouldn't be the case (see old screenshot - paragraph text is in Venturis serif)

Comment: don't mix two problems in one question that is confusing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ok; I edited the question to skip over the harmless warning.

Comment: Try `\fontfamily{\robotofamily}\robotocondensed ` to select the font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer excellent, that worked. Perhaps an incompatibility / change between old and new installation. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, instead of just selecting with `\robotocondensed`, the change is to use `\fontfamily{\robotofamily}\robotocondensed`. Furthermore, I found that the `condensed` option to the `roboto` package creates a new problem where the *other fonts* become condensed as well; in this case the Venturis paragraph text. To fix this problem, remove the `condensed` package option, and redefine the section, subsection etc. headings with the `titling` package to ensure `\robotocondensed` is explicitly selected.